# Is it possible to have more than one canvas on an HTML5 page?

Tags: html, canvas

I was wondering if it is possible to have more than one canvas fully functioning on and HTML5 page. I have tried this a little while ago and it didn't work but I really didn't take time to think about how to do this and it ultimately failed. So is it possible to have more than one canvas fully functioning on an HTML5 page?

Comment: Yes, it possible to have more than one canvas fully functioning on an HTML5 page.

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself and find the answer? It takes less than a minute to write a quick HTML test page, perhaps less than the time it took you to type your question here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var cnv1 = document.getElementById("1");
var ctx1 = cnv1.getContext("2d");
var cnv2 = document.getElementById("2");
var ctx2 = cnv2.getContext("2d");

ctx1.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 75);

ctx2.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 75);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="1" width="100px" height="100px"><p>Canvas doesn't work.</p></canvas>
<canvas id="2" width="100px" height="100px"><p>Canvas doesn't work.</p></canvas>
```

Comment: Run the script in case you still don't believe

Comment: Would you mind rewording your answer as it comes across as a little ambiguous and a touch rude. We were all beginners at some point and have all asked naive questions.

Comment: I see. Answer reworded